# Cannot read network files in my OPC Server C++

Tags: file, networking, opc

A little background info:

PC is a Windows 7 64 bit machine with all SP's and windows updates.
I wrote an OPC server using LightOPC as the base and having issues reading network files as the title says.   If I run the program manually it reads the files just fine.

There are no permissions issues obviously when running it manually but something else happens when the client launches it (FactoryTalk View 8.0).

The problem occurs when the program starts during the normal OPC connection launching. In the code `std::strerror(errno)` function returns

> no such file or directory

which is obviously a lie. So hopefully someone can shed some light on what I can do to adjust the code (maybe some security level up or something like that) to let it read from these network files (about 10 total). I log data to the Windows Event viewer and I log the user name used to attach to the server, it is using `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` at program launch.

Here is 1 of the pieces of code used to read 1 of the files (`fin.is_open()` is returning false so it falls into the else and I am writing the error to the OPC tag so I could debug it):

```
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open("\\\\SCS\\C\\Sorter Software\\Data\\TocStatus.dat"); // open a file    | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app
        if (fin.is_open())
        {
            char buf[512];
            fin.getline(buf, 512);
            char *theString = TrimCString(buf);
            if (strlen(theString))
                mbstowcs_s(NULL, V_BSTR(&tagValues[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC].tvValue), strlen(theString)*2, theString, strlen(theString));

            if (use_window)
                ListView_SetItemText(TheListView, TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC-1, 1, theString);
            if (tagValues[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC].tvState.tsQuality == OPC_QUALITY_BAD)
            {
                tagValues[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC].tvState.tsQuality = OPC_QUALITY_GOOD;
                SetListViewItem(TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC, tagActivationFlags[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC]);
            }
            if (tagValues[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC].tvState.tsQuality != OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)
            {
                tagValues[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC].tvState.tsQuality = OPC_QUALITY_GOOD;
                SetListViewItem(TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC, 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            V_BSTR(&tagValues[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC].tvValue) = SysAllocString(L"UNKNOWN ERROR9                                                                                      ");
            mbstowcs_s(NULL, V_BSTR(&tagValues[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOCLOADED].tvValue), strlen(std::strerror(errno)) * 2, std::strerror(errno), strlen(std::strerror(errno)));
            tagValues[TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC].tvState.tsQuality = OPC_QUALITY_GOOD;
            if (use_window)
            {
                ListView_SetItemText(TheListView, TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC-1, 1, "UNKNOWN");
                SetListViewItem(TAGS_MOTIONTL_STATUS_TOC, 2);
            }
            UpdateConnStatus(false);
        }
        fin.close();
```

Comment: *it is using "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" at program launch.* - There's your problem right there. The SYSTEM account has no access to network files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any way to change SYSTEM account to be able to access them?

Comment: There is no option to change the SYSTEM account. You'll have to choose a different account that has network credentials.

Comment: Wish I could choose the account, its out of my control since the "FactoryTalk" software is what starting it that way.

Comment: You should be able to change the account under which your OPC Server is running in DCOMCNFG utility. For out-of-process servers, the OPC client (FactoryTalk in this case) is not in control of it; it is the COM/DCOM infrastructure of Windows, and consequently, you. In DCOMCNFG, you can choose between running as Launching User or Interactive User (using those is generally not a good idea with OPC), , or a specific user - an account that you specify.

Comment: @ZbynekZ DUDE, JUST AWESOME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   I totally forgot about DCOMCNFG, havent used that since Windows NT days.  All I had to do was find my application in DCOMCNFG, change to Interactive User and that did exaclty what I needed, thanks a million!

Comment: Thank you. Just for record, Interactive User *may* be a good choice in some applications, but normally it isn't. The problems with it include 1) It may be a different user each time somebody logs in, therefore not predictable, and 2) There may be no interactive user on the machine whatsoever (nobody has logged in), in which case the server won't start.